# Using uv to install packages in the bitnami/deepspeed:0.14.0 Docker image fails with 'uv: command not found'

Tags: python, docker, pip, bitnami, deepspeed

If I use the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.11-bullseye

ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

COPY requirements.txt /app

RUN pip install uv && uv pip install --system --no-cache -r requirements.txt
```

Then the packages in `requirements.txt` install just fine. But if I change the first line to

```
FROM bitnami/deepspeed:0.14.0
```

Then suddenly I get the error

```
#8 [4/4] RUN pip install uv && uv pip install --system --no-cache -r requirements.txt
#8 0.629 Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
#8 0.807 Collecting uv
#8 0.867   Downloading uv-0.1.18-py3-none-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (23 kB)
#8 0.896 Downloading uv-0.1.18-py3-none-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (11.0 MB)
#8 2.013    ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 11.0/11.0 MB 9.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#8 2.947 Installing collected packages: uv
#8 3.209 Successfully installed uv-0.1.18
#8 3.421 /bin/bash: line 1: uv: command not found
#8 ERROR: process "/bin/bash -o errexit -o nounset -o pipefail -c pip install uv && uv pip install --system --no-cache -r requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 127
------
 > [4/4] RUN pip install uv && uv pip install --system --no-cache -r requirements.txt:
0.629 Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
0.807 Collecting uv
0.867   Downloading uv-0.1.18-py3-none-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (23 kB)
0.896 Downloading uv-0.1.18-py3-none-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (11.0 MB)

2.947 Installing collected packages: uv
3.209 Successfully installed uv-0.1.18
3.421 /bin/bash: line 1: uv: command not found
------
Dockerfile.mini:11
--------------------
   9 |     
  10 |     # Install dependency packages
  11 | >>> RUN pip install uv && uv pip install --system --no-cache -r requirements.txt
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/bash -o errexit -o nounset -o pipefail -c pip install uv && uv pip install --system --no-cache -r requirements.txt"
```

**Edit:**

I can get it to work if I install the python packages as root:

```
FROM bitnami/deepspeed:0.14.0

USER root

ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

COPY requirements.txt /app

RUN pip install uv && uv pip install --python $(which python) --no-cache -r requirements.txt
```

But is there a way to use [`uv`](https://github.com/astral-sh/uv)  to install python packages in the [`bitnami/deepspeed:0.14.0`](https://github.com/bitnami/containers/tree/main/bitnami/deepspeed) Docker image as the `deepspeed` user?

Answer (score 0):

The installed `uv` binary is not on PATH, and presumably since it's not a regular Python wrapper script, `pip` doesn't print out the helpful warning about that.

Refer to the `.local`-installed `uv` manually:

```
RUN pip install uv && ~/.local/bin/uv pip install --system --no-cache -r requirements.txt
```

Note that `--system` will likely fail since that image is clearly not running these commands as `root`.

(Personally, I would probably not use a `bitnami/deepspeed` image.)

Comment: That is running into some permission errors: `failed to create directory /opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click` .  And I need to use the `bitname/deepspeed` image because the [`deepspeed/deeepspeed` image](https://hub.docker.com/r/deepspeed/deepspeed/tags)  hasn't been updated in two years.

Comment: I got it to work when installing as `root`, see my edit. but I would like to install the packages as the `deepspeed` user.

Comment: As my answer says, `--system` will likely fail. You can create a virtualenv with `uv venv` and install packages in the virtualenv; as far as I know, `uv` doesn't support user-local installs (`pip`'s `--local`).

Comment: Why do you need a specific Deepspeed image in the first place, though, is my question – why can't you just [`uv pip install deepspeed`](https://pypi.org/project/deepspeed/)?